# What is definition of "after a year’s worth of"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

There's a sentence:

```
After a year’s worth of design wrangling, we got down to business.
```

So the problem is I don't understand meaning of **after a year’s worth of** part. Some synonyms or definitions are appreciated.

Tried it on the Web but found only a couple of press article names.

Thank you.

Comment: In your precise context, replacing plain ***a year*** with ***a year's worth*** is a completely meaningless "stylistic flourish" (that might arguably be faintly more "emphatic" about how long that period was, but I can't really see that). In other contexts, such as *I was exhausted by lunchtime, having done a day's worth of work already*, it has a fairly obvious literal meaning (I did the equivalent of a whole day's work before lunchtime), but it's not likely anything like that applies with your example.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/a%20years%20worth

Comment: @MetaEd Really my bad as I use DuckDuckGo on regular basis and have found nothing. Using Bing! before you pointed me to [link] (thesaurus.com/browse/a%20years%20worth) as my second try search engine I found article which you link me to but it's unclear for me that **a years worth** dictionary article should contain also **a year's worth**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A year's time spent on" -- So in your case, after spending a year wrangling over the design, we got down to business.

Comment: Must be a typo (in bold): _after_ **a** _spending a year wrangling..._